# how to fire click event on datagridview when there are more than one columns in table?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   con = new SqlConnection("server=ABHINAVPC;database=timtable;trusted_connection=true");
   con.Open();
   ds = new DataSet(); 
}
private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell =(DataGridViewCell)dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
     if (cell.ValueType.ToString() == "Abhinav")
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Right Name");
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Wrong Name");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is not working about this?

Comment: sir when i am retrieving table which contains only one column then it is firing the event properly but when i am trying to do it with table that contains two columns its not working.